# Buying internal hard drive,how to shift all data from old hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive

I'm thinking of buying a new internal hard drive with larger capacity. My old hard rive is 80gb and a dual boot of ubuntu and windows 7 is installed on it. I'm a total newbie to hardware, so is it possile to shift all data from my old drive to the new one?

I wanna keep all my data and programs and settings, I just need more space, so what do you advise?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want the space to install programs on the system drive, you can put it as a second drive and it will show up in My Computer. You should use the space more effectively: on the system drive (C:) you should install only the programs that you use the most (browser, photo editing program, etc) and on the second drive (the larger one) you should have the games, music, downloads, all the big files. At least this way i find it very effectively. I have a 320 Gb system drive and a 1 Tb extensive space drive. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, i'll now buy a external hdd and add it to my pc.

Comment: External HDDs are very slow, in my opinion. Try to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

- If you already have an external drive on the network or even connectible to your computer via USB. you can make an image of your hard disk to the external hard disk using [ColenZilla](http://clonezilla.org/). It gets everything to that image(OS, files, programs etc). Then replace the computer's internal drive with the new one(it's different from one you saved the hard disk image too). Now boot the machine and run CloneZilla again and install(copy back or clone) the image to the newly inserted internal drive from the network/external drive wherever you had saved the image of your old internal drive.
- If you do not have an external drive/NAS. You will need an USB to IDE/SATA adapter cable or a hard drive enclosure with cable so that you can connect the new hard disk directly to the computer and clone the image of old hard disk to new one(omitting the need for intermediate external disk or NAS)
- Another option is to take the computer and new hard drive to your computer service centre or a repair shop and ask the guy to do it for you. (Just make sure only thing he connects to your computer or hard disk is an extra cable(maybe), for privacy)

**PS**. to run CloneZilla in either step you can use a CD or external bootable USB drive with CloneZilla installed on it - look around for how to do that https://duckduckgo.com/?q=CloneZilla+howto. And there are softwares other than CloneZilla for disk cloning/imaging. But this one is free and open source.

Comment: thanks for answering,but i'll just buy a new external hdd and dedicate  the internal hdd to the os's